# Question on reuse of pointers after passing to functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants

So, when I pass a `const char *` to a function once, can I use it again?  It appears to end up spitting out crap to me.

```
const char *config_file = "file.txt";

function(int x, config_file);
cout << "Number" << x;


secondfunction(int y, config_file);
```

Do I need to make another pointer to config_file?

If so, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is so far from properly structured code, that it is very difficult to determine (1) what it's supposed to do and/or (2) what it does.  A minimal program that demonstrates the problem (looks like 12 lines might do) and an explanation of what it was supposed to do would help a lot.

Comment: This is very confusing, I don't see where config_file is being used, so there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: +1 It's too rare to see SO questions with a descriptive, accurate title.

Comment: Although, about tags: don't use the "function-pointers" tag just  because you have pointers and functions in your question. Similarly, using tag "return-value" because some of your functions return values may be a mischaracterization.

Comment: I've tried to clean it up a bit without changing the meaning of the question (I haven't touched the code since it was hard to tell what you were actually doing). If I've gotten it wrong, you can either fix it or leave a comment explaining how I got it wrong, and I'll have another shot at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, your can use it just fine. Despite the fact that the code you gave is uncompilable, I think I understand what you're asking.

A code segment like:

```
const char *x = "Hello";
fnA (x);
fnB (x);
```

should be just fine.

If you find that `fnB` is not getting what it expects then either:

- `fnA` is changing what `x` points to (normally not possible since it's a `const char *`); or
- some unshown piece of code is changing the pointer itself; or
- something is corrupting the memory.

---

Try this code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

static void fnA (const char *a) {
    std::cout << "fnA: [" << a << "]" << std::endl;
}
static void fnB (const char *b) {
    std::cout << "fnB: [" << b << "]" << std::endl;
}
int main (void) {
    const char *x = "Hello";
    fnA (x);
    fnB (x);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs, as expected:

```
fnA: [Hello]
fnB: [Hello]
```